# Errors in View.java file near the import statement(android sdk)

Tags: android

I am importing View class in android like " `import android.view.View;` " to use in my project.
But the View class itself has some errors.

> Cannot resolve symbol 'CallSuper'
>   Cannot resolve symbol 'ColorInt'

In View.java :-

```
import android.annotation.CallSuper;
import android.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.annotation.FloatRange;
import android.annotation.IdRes;
import android.annotation.IntDef;
import android.annotation.IntRange;
import android.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
```

Comment: `View` class does not have any error . What you are seeing is de compiled Source for Android SDK . You should not worry about this ..

Comment: shall i reinstall android sdk or android studio to resolve this?

Comment: You don't need to do anything just build your project, if it builds without error all good.